# Perspective camera RealityKit

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I created a RealityKit project which loads objects (usdz files). Using the LiDAR is really great for occlusion and be able to see the real world mesh.
I would like to use something found in the Apple's documentation : [Perspective Camera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/perspectivecamera). If I well understood this could be compare as a third person camera.

I created a dedicated button in my arView which, when called, execute the code following :

```
let cameraEntity = PerspectiveCamera()
    cameraEntity.camera.far = 10
    cameraEntity.camera.fieldOfViewInDegrees = 60
    cameraEntity.camera.near = 0.01
    
let cameraAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: .zero)
    cameraAnchor.children.append(cameraEntity)
    
self.arView.scene.anchors.append(cameraAnchor)
```

When is code is called the the become black.... I do not understand how to place the camera to see the scanned mesh.
If someone has an idea ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where the USDZ you're looking at is located. I think the default will mean the camera is located at the origin looking in the direction of [0, 0, -1].
You could change this using the [`Entity.look(at:from:upVector:relativeTo:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/3244094-look) method. Making sure that your `from:` parameter is far enough from the centre of your USDZ object.